# Javascript prototype function returning function throw the error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a function to returning my function by reverse order, later while i call it, i can't get the result. instead the error thrown.

any one tell me the way i do is wrong?

```
String.prototype.reverse = function(st){
    return st.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var myString = "sample string to reverse";

var reversed = myString.reverse();
```

i understand my way is wrong. any one can help me to my function corrected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'this'. As you are not passing any parameter to reverse.

```
  String.prototype.reverse = function(){
      return this.split('').reverse().join('');
  }

  var myString = "sample string to reverse";

  var reversed = myString.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are configured the function to accept parameter here you actually need no parameter, just change it to:

```
 String.prototype.reverse = function(){
      return this.split('').reverse().join('');
  }

  var myString = "sample string to reverse";

  var reversed = myString.reverse();
```